# svn repo borked by git svn remove and add?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, svnadmin

I had a directory, `Dir`, that I removed with git svn, and then I added `dir`. By checking this two-commit in, svn is no longer able to update, hanging on the inability to add a directory which already exists.

Is there a way to remove the svn commits themselves that does not require access to the filesystem on which the repository sits?

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Failed to add directory 'dir': a versioned directory of the same name already exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout the svn repository. Fix it with SVN only. Then fetch in the other repo. This should solve it.

Comment: This doesn't actually let you remove commits, but the issue was that the git commit didn't remove the svn directory, as git has no notion of adding or removing directories.